# Testing TapGesture with 6 repeats (iOS and Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, integration-testing

This might be a fun one.  I'm setting up UI testing in XCode.
One part of my app requires the user to tap on the screen 6 times to perform a particular action.  The code is below.

```
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action:#selector(self.doSomething(_:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 6
        aView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Where I am having trouble is testing this gesture recognizer.  The following code is created by the test recorder, but doesn't work when just tested.

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let elem = app.otherElements.containingType(.Image, identifier:"elementName").element
    elem.tap()
    elem.tap()
    elem.tap()
    elem.tap()
    elem.tap()
    elem.tap()
```

I even tried adding a slight delay between each element (about I've tried values between 1.0 and 0.02 seconds), but nothing seems to actually work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've found so far.  At its fastest, a tap takes a little over one second in the UI tester, which is WAY too long (not even close by a wide margin).  So I had to make a workaround (aka: a hack)

Here is my work-around.

1. IN the UITests target I added an "Other Swift Flags" **"-D TEST"**.  Now from my code I can use preprocessor checks in my main project.  '#if TEST'.
2. I added a button to the ui on the view in question.  Wired it via a standard "touch up inside" event handler.
3. In my view controller I did something like this:

   #if !TEST

   myButton.hidden = true

   #endif
4. Modified my UI test code to find that button and do a simple tap instead.